# Why are green monkeys (West Africa, Barbados) green?

Tags: zoology

Melanin in fur, hair and bare skin (eumelanin, pheomelanin) does not create green colors, which is why green mammals are so rare....

Green sloths (Americas) are covered in some sort of algae, which explains their coloration....

But what about green monkeys?  I can find no explanation....